Does atomic radius matter when doping a crystal?
My question isn't specifically about semiconductors, but that's perhaps a well understood example to work from.
Silicon crystals are typically doped with Group III and Group V elements. In terms of providing or accepting an electron, it doesn't matter which element from the group is used. Does it matter which element is used in terms of "fitting in" with the silicon crystal? Would the larger elements, such as Thallium or Bismuth, cause disruptions in the crystal?
If it matters, it can be assumed that the dopants are introduced while the crystal is grown, instead of having them injected after the fact.

Aside of the size, there can be problem with Tl or Bi unwillingly providing their 6s electrons due s orbital relativistic contraction, preferring  +1 resp. +3 oxidation state.

It's a good question, and Bi-doped Si is being investigated for LASERS and other uses (https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/1.2355745, https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S136980011830249X, https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.094404), and Th-dope Ge, as well: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1369800124007145

Some dopants may have extremely low solid solubility, so they can't be introduced while growing the crystal.

@DrMoishePippik Clearly, if the question focuses on the example of increasing the conductivity of silicon at sufficiently high temperature, only solubility matters. OTOH, if the goal is not to disrupt the lattice, the answer is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hume-Rothery_rules
